# Marvel Comic with Ant-Man and Spider-Man holding a weapon

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics

I am looking for a story which I can only remember one page from.

It starts with the villain saying something to the effect of "you don't dare to fire that". It then cuts to a panel with Spider-Man holding a weapon, with Ant-Man (who is normal sized) next to him. The next panel has Ant-man press the button to trigger the weapon.

Art style was definitely newer, but as I am unfamiliar with comics I am unable to provide an accurate age, but it was probably Ageless Age.

I have found the panel, here it is: [image: comic panel]

As is plainly visible, I got who was holding the device and who presses the button mixed up.

What is the comic this is from?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for ID questions to see if it helps you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.  For example, approximately when did you read this?

Comment: @DavidW I saw the panel sometime last year, but I have never read to comic itself

Comment: Can you describe anything about the villain (costume/main colours etc)? What was the weapon like? Do you know which Ant-Man (or spiderman for that matter) it was?

Comment: @Jack the weapon was slightly larger than the average gun, had a guard connecting the end of the barrel, and was basically a cylinder on a handle

Comment: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TxY4dYr64kgC&pg=PT101&lpg=PT101&dq=%22ant+man+pulls+the+trigger%22&source=bl&ots=M-Sg1NEHzN&sig=ACfU3U0F5xBHssyUcgOYDsqZHb0unEN4hg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxp5yLnbLiAhXrVBUIHebOCUsQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22ant%20man%20pulls%20the%20trigger%22&f=false

Comment: I am looking for the comic which it is from

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is *[Marvel Adventures: The Avengers #26](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/21533/marvel_adventures_the_avengers_2006_26)*

> It's the bottom of the ninth, the Avengers are down by two, two strikes down and bases loaded. The stakes for the Cosmic Pennant have never been higher. How will Galactus call this one? Okay... we admit. We have no idea what's going on in this story. Kirk drew the cover, and now Parker has to come up with something. THAT'S GOOD COMICS!!!

The weapon in question is the [Ultimate Nullifier](https://www.syfy.com/syfywire/stuff-we-love-avengers-baseball-galactus)

> Galactus, of course, isn't easily swayed. He's hungry, he wants a planet, and he finds inhabited worlds particularly satisfying. The aliens know from Earth history that Galactus was once swayed away from the planet by being bribed with the extraordinarily powerful Ultimate Nullifier, but even after Ant-Man manages to steal the device from Galactus' ship, the Devourer of Worlds isn't worried. He's now convinced that the Avengers wouldn't dare actually use such a device, as it would end life as they know it. Spider-Man calls his bluff, because he's Spider-Man, and activates the Nullifier.

FWIW, I found it via a Google search for *ant-man spider-man galactus*, which brought up the panel, as well as one of Ant-Man declaring, "The Ultimate Nullifier!", which led to me adding that to the search query, which mentioned the issue. From there, I just looked for reviews of said issue to get more details.